# how to convert eosio::public_key to c public_key?

Tags: cryptography, public-key

In the vote.cpp, they use this type of public key:

```
namespace eosio {
   struct public_key {
      unsigned_int        type;
      std::array<char,33> data;
friend bool operator == ( const public_key& a, const public_key& b ) {
        return std::tie(a.type,a.data) == std::tie(b.type,b.data);
      }
      friend bool operator != ( const public_key& a, const public_key& b ) {
        return std::tie(a.type,a.data) != std::tie(b.type,b.data);
      }
      EOSLIB_SERIALIZE( public_key, (type)(data) )
   };
}
```

however, when use the recover_key() method in crypto.h
the public key should be like this:

```
struct public_key {
   char data[34];
};
```

I'd like to know how to convert the first public_key to the second?
when I store the second in the table, I can't use the get table action.